# How to get objects/locations from google mp cluster on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Is there a way to get **objects/locations/markers** from **google map cluster** on iOS. How to get that **list of objects** from a **cluster** when user **taps** on it. Is there a solution in Swift? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I just used method below from the `GMUClusterRendererDelegate` delegate and casted `userData` to `GMUCluster`. After that I just get its `items`.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
     guard let cluster = marker.userData as? GMUCluster else { return false }
     print(cluster.items)
     print("didTap CLUSTER")
     return true
}
```